# How does getDeclaredMethod work in java

Tags: java

I'm not sure how "getDeclaredMethod" works in java, can some one explain how to get the value from the method, this is what i have..

I want to get this value (body_number), which is in the AIBody Class.

```
public int getBody_number() {
    return body_number;
}
```

And in the same class i have this

```
Method m = body_A.getUserData().getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getBody_number", null);
```

How would i get the "body_number" value from m?

ps getUserData is a class of the object that i want to get the method answer out of 
Any help would be great.

Adam

Comment: Please read the javadoc.

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/reflections.html) blog post helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Since `m` is an instance method of whatever object is returned by `body_A.getUserData()` and it takes no arguments, you'd do something like this:

```
Method m = body_A.getUserData().getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
    "getBody_number", null
);
int val = (Integer) m.invoke(body_A.getUserData());
```

(You'll have to wrap it in a try/catch or declare the appropriate `throws` in the method in which this code executes.)

Of course, once you have the `Method` object, you are not limited to invoking it for the object returned by `body_A.getUserData()`; you can pass it any instance of `AIBody`.

Reference: [`Method.invoke()` doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

However, I have to agree with [what Bhaskar wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295187/535871): why are you using reflection for this? You can simply call:

```
int val = body_A.getUserData().getBody_number();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but getUserData() is a object, and getBody_number is a method within the object, so i want to get the method and find the answer of the method, but im not sure is that possible.

Comment: @AdamEdney - That's exactly what my code does. (Your code was fine for setting `m` to the `Method` object based on the class and the method name.) The first argument to `Method.invoke` will become `this` inside the method when it executes. The remaining arguments to `invoke` (if any) become the arguments to the method.

Comment: Sorry about that i didn't know what invoke did so i guessed that it wouldn't work, sorry about that and thanks for the help, i think this will be a very valuable lesson, im new here can i give you plus one reputation or something.

Comment: @AdamEdney - I'm glad the answer was useful. Take a look at the help topics [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 1):

You get back an instance of [java.lang.reflect.Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), on which you use the invoke method

```
int val = ((Integer)m.invoke(body_A.getUserData())).intValue()
```

You may want to consider why you are using reflection in this case and not just

```
body_A.getUserData().getBody_number()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but im didn't tell you that getUserData() is a object so i don't think that would work, and getBody_number is a method within the object, so i want to get the method and find the answer of the method, but im not sure is that possible. is that correct or is there anyother way

Comment: @AdamEdney you can typecast an Object to the correct type and invoke the method, there is no need for reflection. You know that it has a method getBody_number, you can type cast it to any appropriate type that declare the method and invoke it. In the event the type cast fails, the reflective method would generally fail too, unless you have 2 unrealted type hierarchies with the same method, which would be more concerting from a OOP/D standpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked, you been really helpful sorry about the  simple question